# Why is my chili plant drying out when the soil is moist?

Tags: diagnosis, chili

[image]What is happening to my chili plant? The soil is moist but the leaves are drying out. I have the plant in a pot in the bathroom with plenty of light from the skylight.

There are plenty of flowers but no chili have appeared.

Answer (score 3):

The humidity of the air may be a bit too low, and your flowers also may not be getting properly pollinated.  The plant looks pretty healthy from what little I can see of it, so I'd try to increase the humidity a bit and look up the best way to hand-pollinate your future flowers and see if that helps it set fruit.  Many solanums just need to be "jostled" a bit now and then to cause the pollen to fall from the stamens onto the pistil.  If your pepper has exposed stamens and pistils, then you will probably want to use a Q-tip or a small soft brush to move the pollen around.

Answer (score 1):

those are just aborts, they happen, usually at the start of the fruiting season, better pollination helps. there is also a commercial spray for tomatoes you could try "Bonide 543 Ready-to-Use Tom/Blossom Set".